# Non capturing group in regex not working as expected

Tags: regex

Trying to write a simple regex to match either of the following formats: `XX-XXXXXX-XX-XX-XX` or `XX-XXXXXX-XX-XX-XX-XX` where `X` is a number `(0-9)` or an alpha character (case insensitive).

I have tested the following expression:

```
/[0-9A-Za-z]{2}-[0-9A-Za-z]{6}-[0-9A-Za-z]{2}-[0-9A-Za-z]{2}-[0-9A-Za-z]{2}(?:-[0-9A-Za-z]{2})/
```

where the final `-XX` is a non capturing group.

I am trying to test against the following entries:

```
0F-F5G67E-H4-j6-j7
0F-F5G67E-H4-j6-j7-8J
```

But, it only matches the second one.

Heres the link for testing: http://regexr.com/3eebe

I will appreciate if any pro regexers can lend a hand.

Thanks

Comment: What is not working as expected?

Comment: non-capturing group still requires the token to be there.  Did you mean optional?  So add `?` at the end.

Comment: @Karakfa If I add the '?' at the end it matches with the second format only not the first. I want to be able to match both formats using the same regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark the group as optional by adding a `?` at the end:

```
/[0-9A-Za-z]{2}-[0-9A-Za-z]{6}-[0-9A-Za-z]{2}-[0-9A-Za-z]{2}-[0-9A-Za-z]{2}(?:-[0-9A-Za-z]{2})?/
```

Comment: If I add the '?' at the end it matches with the second format only not the first. I want to be able to match both formats using the same regex.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add ? (meaning "zero or one time") after your group `/[0-9A-Za-z]{2}-[0-9A-Za-z]{6}-[0-9A-Za-z]{2}-[0-9A-Za-z]{2}-[0-9A-Za-z]{2}(?:-[0-9A-Za-z]{2})?/`

Also, add `g` flag to match both groups in your testing environment.

And finally, why not just combine last three groups together: `/[\w]{2}-[\w]{6}(?:-[\w]{2}){3,4}/g`?

Comment: `[\w]` == `\w` != `[0-9A-Za-z]`

Comment: Thanks the /g was missing in the testing environment!

Answer (score 0):

Next time you can use quantifier `{3,4}`:

```
[0-9A-Za-z]{2}-[0-9A-Za-z]{6}(?:-[0-9A-Za-z]{2}){3,4}
```

View it [Online](http://regexr.com/3eeci)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `?` following the non-capturing group so add a `?` and set the `g` flag

```
[0-9A-Za-z]{2}-[0-9A-Za-z]{6}-[0-9A-Za-z]{2}-[0-9A-Za-z]{2}-[0-9A-Za-z]{2}(?:-[0-9A-Za-z]{2})?
```